# Issues centering d3 graph in a bootstrap div column

Tags: html, css, d3.js

This is my current d3 graph: [image]

This is my div for it

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col justify-content-md-center" id="controls_container">
            </div>
            <div class="col justify-content-md-center center-block" align="center">
                <div id="chart"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The graph is under the #chart div. But as you can see, it's not quite centered... I've tried adding justify-content-md-center, I've tried align center, but I'm at a bit of a loss at this point. I am using bootstrap css.

Comment: I believe you have manually translate it by finding the dimensions of the parent div

Comment: @UmeshMaharshi yup that was the issue